# Disable mic in google action after the response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a google action using dialogflow agent. Now after every response from the dialogflow agent mic is in active state, i want mic to be inactive state after the response from the agent. Is there a way where i can configure in google action to deactivate mic after the response?

Comment: Use conv.close instead of conv.ask if you are using fulfillment. Or you can enable the button under the responses in dialogflow intent.

Comment: conv.close will exit from the conversation @snuffbox. I don't want to exit from the conversation, just deactivate the mic.

Comment: Can you update the question to describe a conversation to illustrate why you want to close the mic, but keep the conversation open? Or what you expect to happen with the conversation once the microphone is closed? And how the user would be expected to continue the conversation again?

Answer (score 1):

Actions on Google has an intentional conversational experience. You start the conversation with an invocation, it responds, you respond, and so on.

If an Action wants to end the conversation, it can do that and close the mic.

The user experience of an Action providing a response and not expecting the user to reply is not behavior encouraged by the platform.

Comment: so, there is no way we can deactivate the mic without exiting the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been tacking on a randomly selected "what's next' prompt.  I don't know if it will pass review though:

```
const whatNextPhrases = [
'What else can I help with?',
'What can I help with next?',
'What would you like to do?',
'Can I do anything else for you?' 
];
```

I can't comment due to rep, but to answer Prisoner's question - there are use cases where it's just poor conversational flow for the agent to immediately reply.  For example, if you present a list of (up to) 30 items to a user, you're expecting the user to take a moment to "take it in" before asking her next question.  It's like if you go into Tiffany & Co and say "may I see your diamond rings between $1500 and $2000" and the clerk takes out 6 rings, puts them on the counter and immediately continues the conversation with like "which one do you want"?  Any concierge or shopping experience the conversation should be able to reopened at the user's discretion without prompting with mic.  What's interesting is Google has actions like limerick which do exactly that.  Why?  Because after it reads the limerick, it probably figures you want to look at it some more before asking for another.